# How to configure dependency injection to allow only one instance of a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

During an Interview I was asked this.

We use in our project unity container for dependency injection. Which gets initialized in `Globals.asax` using `Bootstrapper.Initialise();`

My DI

```
public class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }
        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterService(container);
            return container;
        }
        public static void RegisterService(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<ILibraryService, LibraryService>();
        }

    }
```

There were two questions .

1. How many times the DI is initialized through out the project ?
2. How to configure dependency injection to allow only one instance of a class?

This are pretty basic question, I am goofing them badly. Can you suggest some answers for them.
The project environment is VS2015,C#,MVC 5,Unity ,Repository pattern, EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**  DI conatainer will be initialized once on when application is started (`Application_Start()` event in **Global.asax**).

**2.** They were asking about `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`
There is an overload of `RegisterType` method which takes parameter an instance of type [LifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649437.aspx) , so that instance is created once and that instance will be used every time, it will not create new object every time for dependency resolution now:

```
container.RegisterType<ILibraryService, LibraryService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

From MSDN:

> **ContainerControlledLifetimeManager** which registers an existing object as a singleton instance. For this lifetime manager Unity returns the same instance of the registered type or object each time you call the Resolve or ResolveAll method or when the dependency mechanism injects instances into other classes. This lifetime manager effectively implements a singleton behavior for objects.

You can read more about Life Time Manager at [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.lifetimemanager.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, @ehsan for the answer. If the object is only created once using containercontrolledlifetimemanager then if some other action try to access it , Will this create any type of thread locking

Comment: it applies singleton on the instance so it should i think, but i am not sure about that, you can read that link for more details, hope you get answer of your this question there :)

Answer (score -1):

Lets say we've to pass person object then using DI pass PersonWrapper object and then use method  GetPerson() to fetch singleton thePerson

```
public class PersonWrapper
{
    private static Person thePerson = null;

    public static GetPerson
    {
       get
       {
           if(thePerson==null) { thePerson = new Person();}
           return thePerson;
       }
    }
}
```