# EF6 reading data with NOLOCK while using a single connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, nolock

I want one DBContext per API call while allowing me to use NOLOCK on some SELECT calls. I use unity's DI to manage the life cycle of my DBContext.

I built some helper methods to help me with making NOLOCK queries when I select massive amounts of data so I don't lock the table for other processes.

```
public static class EfExtensions
    {
        public static List<T> ToListWithNoLock<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            List<T> result = new List<T>();
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }, 
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                result = query.ToList();
                scope.Complete();
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Then I use it like this

```
_dashboardDbContext.ImageDownload.Where(x => x.status != ImageDownloadStatuses.failed && x.status != ImageDownloadStatuses.downloaded)
                .OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDateTime)
                .Take(_imageProcessingImagesPerExecution)
                .ToListWithNoLock();
```

This ToListWithNoLock helper function seems to cause a lot of errors. If I enforce a single DBContext using "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager" ([How to configure dependency injection to allow only one instance of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112101/how-to-configure-dependency-injection-to-allow-only-one-instance-of-a-class)) then I get
`The underlying provider failed on EnlistTransaction. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.`
Uncertain, but I believe this is happening becuse my TransactionScope is trying to create a new DBContext for its own use.

Now if I remove "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager" the restriction of a single DBContext per API call. I see start getting this error.
`System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`
This also leads me to believe TransactionScope is connecting and reading the entities that I later in the code try to do something with.

I assume that I need to take the current DBContext and somehow provide that to the TransactionScope to use, so it doesn't try to create its own DBContext.

Comment: NOLOCK doesn't mean dont' take locks. It won't fix bad queries, it will only *create* more problems like taking a Schema lock on the entire table, returning duplicate rows and even throwing random errors. Instead of trying to cover up performance problems with `NOLOCK`, find and fix them

Comment: Is `status` covered by an index? If not, filtering with it will result in a full table scan , no matter what hints are used. The server simply has no way of knowing which row in eg 5M rows matches the desired status. NOLOCK won't fix this. If the query returns 1M rows, performance will bad *and* those rows will still be locked

Comment: I strongly advise reading [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: If you are using EF Core you can use an Interceptor. But I concur, you really shouldn't use `ReadUncommitted`. If you are really worried about blocking then at least use `Snapshot`

Comment: `If I enforce a single DBContext` that's a critical bug too - a DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. It's meant to exist only for a single business operation or web request. Once it's disposed, all pending changes are discarded without requiring an explicit transaction and rollback. If you use a singleton instance, *all* objects loaded through it will remain in memory, *all* changes will remain active until you call SaveChanges. You may thing you're creating a single item and end up performing abandoned changes from 10-20 requests ago

Comment: I think that coding something doing a massive lock of hundreds of records is a senseless operation. It's not like one can lock the entire database. Rather, try to change your approach to your problem. Optimistic concurrency was invented for this.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, everyone. It sounds like a got a lot of research to do. A big part of my problem is this code base is inherited and it is a spiraling case of bad practices used to work around previous bad practices. The whole stack needs to be thrown out. 

I'll come back and comment once I find a better way of dealing with this.